# How to convert a string to enum in Godot?

Tags: enums, godot, gdscript

Using Godot 3.4, I have an enum setup as:

```
enum {
    STRENGTH, DEXTERITY, CONSTITUTION, INTELLIGENCE, WISDOM, CHARISMA
}
```

And I would like to be able to make the string "STRENGTH" return the enum value (0). I would like the below code to print the first item in the array however it currently presents an error that STRENGTH is an invalid get index.

```
boost = "STRENGTH"
print(array[boost])
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a function to turn a string into something that can be recognised as an enum?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, your enum needs a name. Without the name, the enum is just a fancy way to make a series of constants. For the purposes of this answer, I'll use `MyEnum`, like this:

```
enum MyEnum {
    STRENGTH, DEXTERITY, CONSTITUTION, INTELLIGENCE, WISDOM, CHARISMA
}
```

Now, we can refer to the enum and ask it about its elements. In particular, we can figure out what is the value associated with a name like this:

```
    var boost = "DEXTERITY"
    print("Value of ", boost, ": ", MyEnum.get(boost))
```

That should print:

```
Value of DEXTERITY: 1
```

---

By the way, if you want to get the name from the value, you can do this:

```
    var value = MyEnum.DEXTERITY
    print("Name of ", value, ": ", MyEnum.keys()[value])
```

That should print:

```
Name of 1: DEXTERITY
```

---

What you are getting is just a regular dictionary preset with the contents of the enum. So, we can ask it about all the values:

```
    for boost in MyEnum:
        print(boost)
```

Which will print:

```
STRENGTH
DEXTERITY
CONSTITUTION
INTELLIGENCE
WISDOM
CHARISMA
```

And we can also ask it if it has a particular one, for example `print(MyEnum.has("ENDURANCE"))` prints `False`.

*And yes you could edit the dictionary. It is just a dictionary you get initialized with the values of the enum.*

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Godot 4.2+ for Enum entries with a custom Integer value, like:
```
enum Facing { LEFT = -1, RIGHT = 1 }
print("Facing: ", _facing, " Facing.enum = %s" % [Facing.keys()[_facing]])
```
The `_facing` property correctly switches between -1 and 1, but the Keys lookup always returns RIGHT (I'm guessing because the ordinals are 0 and 1).