# (Godot Engine) How do I know which exported enum flags are enabled in script

Tags: dictionary, enums, godot, gdscript

By using the Godot engine and writing in the GDScript language,
let's say I have an enum declared as:

```
enum eTextMode {CHAR, NUMBER, SYMBOLS_TEXT, SYMBOLS_ALL}
```

And an export variable as:

```
export(eTextMode, FLAGS) var _id: int = 0
```

In the inspector panel I can see which flag is selected or not, but **how can I know in code which specifically flag is selected?**

By selecting in the inspector, for example: the *NUMBER* and *SYMBOLS_TEXT* flags, the *_id* variable will be set as 5

My approach is the following hard-coded dictionary:

```
var _selected_flags: Dictionary = {
    CHAR = _id in [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15],
    NUMBER = _id in [2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15],
    SYMBOLS_TEXT = _id in [4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    SYMBOLS_ALL = _id in [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
}
```

Resulting in:

```
{CHAR:True, NUMBER:False, SYMBOLS_ALL:False, SYMBOLS_TEXT:True}
```

The above result is exactly what I'm expecting (a dictionary with string keys as they are defined in the *enum* with a *boolean* value representing the selection state).

**How could I manage to do this dynamically for any *enum* regardless of size?**

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

One tacky solution that I could manage is by not using an *enum* at all, but instead a *dictionary* like the following example:

```
const dTextMode: Dictionary = {CHAR = false, NUMBER = false, SYMBOLS_TEXT = false, SYMBOLS_ALL = false}
export(Dictionary) var m_dTextMode: Dictionary = dTextMode setget Set_TextMode, Get_TextMode

func Get_TextMode() -> Dictionary: return m_dTextMode
func Set_TextMode(_data: Dictionary = m_dTextMode) -> void: m_dTextMode = _data
```

An exported *dictionary* is not as good-looking as an exported *enum* with *FLAGS*, and by following this approach it kind of invalidates my initial problem.

By selecting *CHAR* and *SYMBOLS_TEXT* in the exported dictionary from the inspector, and then calling `print(self.Get_TextMode())` the result is indeed what I expected:

```
{CHAR:True, NUMBER:False, SYMBOLS_ALL:False, SYMBOLS_TEXT:True}
```

I still can't figure out though how to achieve this result by using the `export(*enum, FLAGS)` aproach.

Edit: also, the setter function is not feasible to be used in script since the user must know to duplicate the *dTextMode* constant first, edit it and set is as an argument.

Comment: By the way, if you have an enum, you have a dictionary, see [How to convert a string to enum in Godot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70227444/402022), and for the flags you can do bit shifting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Thearot. I am aware of the enum acting like a dict. and also how to extract .keys() and/or .values() from it. But I don't know about bit shifting.

Comment: The extends of the documentation on bit shifting in Godot 3 documentation seems to be limited to mention the `<<` and `>>` operators [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html). The situation is better in Godot 4. Anyway, if you have worked the `<<` operator in another language, you know what to do. I have an answer about collision layer that explains it: [Passing layers for Physics2DShapeQueryParameters to check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68816495/402022).

Comment: Thank you again, based on this information, I have managed to come-up with a solution (which may not be the best but it's working).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments from @Thearot from my first answer, I have managed to figure out the following solution which meets all expectations, with one caveat: it seems like an overkill solution...

```
enum eTestFlags {FLAG_1, FLAG_2, FLAG_3, FLAG_5, FLAG_6}
export(eTestFlags, FLAGS) var m_iTestFlags: int = 0 setget Set_TestFlags

func Get_TestFlags() -> Dictionary: return self._get_enum_flags(m_iTestFlags, eTestFlags)
func Set_TestFlags(_id: int = m_iTestFlags) -> void: m_iTestFlags = _id

func _get_enum_flags(_val_selected: int, _enum: Dictionary, _bit_check_limit: int = 32) -> Dictionary:
    var _enum_keys: Array = _enum.keys() ; _enum_keys.invert()
    var _bin_string: String = "" 
    var _val_temp: int = 0 
    var _val_count: int = _bit_check_limit - int(_is_pow2(_bit_check_limit))
    while(_val_count >= 0): 
        _val_temp = _val_selected >> _val_count
        _bin_string += "1" if _val_temp & 1 else "0"
        _val_count -= 1
    var _bin_string_padded: String = "%0*d" % [_enum_keys.size(), int(_bin_string)]
    var _result_dict: Dictionary = {}
    for _str_id in range(_bin_string_padded.length(), 0, -1):
        _result_dict[_enum_keys[_str_id - 1]] = bool(_bin_string_padded[_str_id - 1] == "1")
    return _result_dict

func _is_pow2(_value: int) -> bool:
    return _value && (not (_value & (_value - 1)))
```

Now, if I `print(self.Get_TestFlags())` after selecting *FLAG_2* and *FLAG_6* the result is:

```
{FLAG_1:False, FLAG_2:True, FLAG_3:False, FLAG_5:False, FLAG_6:True}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track but overcomplicating things. Without going too much into the math (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field)), here's what you'd do in Godot:

```
enum eTextMode {CHAR, NUMBER, SYMBOLS_TEXT, SYMBOLS_ALL}
export(eTextMode, FLAGS) var _id: int = 0

func _ready() -> void:
    for modeName in eTextMode:
        var bit_flag_value: int = int(pow(2, eTextMode[modeName]))
        if _id & bit_flag_value:
            printt("Flagged", modeName)
```

You can access the named fields of your enum like elements in an Array/Dictionary by default (iterate through the keys, get their 0-based index as values). The above math trick turns the 0-based index into the correct bit flag number, and if you (single) '&' it with the combined bit-flags value you can check whether or not that flag is set.